# How do I bind to a function that has been passed in to a child component via a prop so that I can call it in a function in the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In the code below, can someone advise on how access the function stored in the `closeModal` prop that is passed in to the child `QRScan` component?

I've tried `this.props.closeModal.bind(this)` in the constructor of `QRScan` but when I call `this.props.closeModal()` in the `_onBarCodeRead` function I get an `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.closedModal')` error.

The props are definitely getting passed in to the constructor, I just can't seem to bind the function correctly. Any help much appreciated!

```
class Test extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }

_test(){
  console.log("test worked")
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <QRScan closeModal={this._test}/>
    </View>
  }
}
```

Child class:

```
class QRScan extends React.Component {

constructor(props)
{
 super(props)
 console.log(this.props)
 this.props.closeModal.bind(this);
}

render() {
   return (
    <BarcodeScanner
      onBarCodeRead={this._onBarCodeRead}
      width={windowWidth}
      height={windowWidth * cameraAspectRatio}
      style={styles.camera}>
      <View style={styles.rectangleContainer}>
        <View style={styles.rectangle} />
      </View>
    </BarcodeScanner>
  );
 }
 _onBarCodeRead(e) {
   console.log(e);
   Vibration.vibrate();
   this.props.closeModal();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually the `this._onBarCodeRead` is not bound correctly.

In the child component's constructor you need to add following
`this._onBarCodeRead = this._onBarCodeRead.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Binding a function does not modify the function in-place. Instead, it returns the resultant function, which you can assign to a variable.

So in theory, you could do `this.props.closeModal = this.props.closeModal.bind(this);` but that will not work for react. So instead I would recommend creating a method on the class, bind it, and access the props from there. For example:

```
class QRScan extends React.Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this)
  }
  closeModal() {
    this.props.closeModal.call(this);
  }
}
```

Of course, a generally recommended way of doing things would advise keeping `this` within the class, rather than passing it to your props methods.

To get your code to work, I'd imagine you have to do the same binding with your `this._onBarCodeRead` method.